# php convert date in iso gmt format

Tags: php, date, iso, gmt

Hello I need to store a duration `(0 à 24h)` in my database in the format 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

So how to convert a value, Eg-: 2:00 to 1970-01-01T02:00:00.000Z

I tried this but the date isn't in GMT format

```
$date   = "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z";
$v      = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('+2 hour', strtotime($date)));
$conn->update('measure', array('observence' => $v), array('id_measure' => 34943));
```

> It return   : 1970-01-01T03:00:00+0100
>
> What I need : 1970-01-01T02:00:00.000Z

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you read [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: A timestamp is just a single specific time, not a range of times (duration) - you'd be better off with 2 columns in the table: *"start_time"* and *"end_time"*

Comment: Aside `1970-01-01T03:00:00+0100` and `1970-01-01T02:00:00.000Z` are actually equivalent, just different timezones.

Comment: i need to write in data base of an existing script who i can't modify. i agree it's a good format to store an average duration but I have to keep the existing format for backward compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom format `"Y-m-d\TH:i:s\.000\Z"` instead of `DATE_ISO860`